# Is there is any way I can make filtering inside models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I create custom Account model and I add view columns like **is_student, is_teacher**. So I make another class in another app so how can I do filter something like this in models.

Accounts app models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student              = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher              = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()
```

Main app models.py

```
from accounts.models import Account
a = Account.objects.filter(is_student=True)
class Students(models.Model):
    student = models.ManyToManyField(a, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I want is that to make relationship between Students table and Accounts

> (only those is_student = True)

Comment: Don't understand your question. Please, can you edit it and tell us exactly what you need to do?

Comment: okay I will explain it well

Comment: If you want to specify requirements that needed to be able to add record via M2M, then this should goes to validation rules. You can't define a query set or properties as target model for M2M (and actually other fields)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's even possible. Tables exist before data. So you create tables and then insert data. You can decide after which data to insert.
And don't name your table plural: `Students`

Here is a solution:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    # this means a student can have many accounts and an account can be linked with many students 
    account = models.ManyToManyField(Account, related_name="students", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It might not be good to have an account linked with many students. 
I would do:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    # this means a student can only have one  account and an account can only be linked with one student
    account = models.OneToOneField(Account, related_name="student", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If you want to get active users, just do in your view:

```
active_students = Student.objects.filter(account__is_active=True)
```